# Converting jQuery $.extend to pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am trying to do away with jQuery as I only need it for so few things, and instead use pure JavaScript

**I had this original code:**

```
this.bar = el.find('.bar');
this.options = $.extend({
    delay: $.toInt(el.data('delay')) || 2000
}, options);
```

**And I tried to convert it with this:**

```
function foo(el, options) {

    ..................

    this.bar = el.querySelectorAll(".bar");
    this.options = extend({
        delay: parseInt(el.data('delay')) || 2000 < -- - problem
    }, options);
}
```

---

```
function extend(first, second) {
    for (var secondProp in second) {
        var secondVal = second[secondProp];
        if (secondVal && Object.prototype.toString.call(secondVal) === "[object Object]") {
            first[secondProp] = first[secondProp] || {};
            extend(first[secondProp], secondVal);
        } else {
            first[secondProp] = secondVal;
        }
    }
    return first;
};
```

---

**But I am receiving this error:**

> "Uncaught TypeError: el.data is not a function"

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`el` is DOM object reference, it is not jQuery object, so you cannot call jQuery methods on it.

To get `data-*` attribute value in VanillaJS, you can use [**dataset**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

Use

```
el.dataset.delay
```

If you *want* to use jQuery method you can wrap the element reference in jQuery

```
$(el).data('delay')
```

Comment: Since you are on a roll, how would you convert this to pure JS: ---> this.bar.find("[data-src],[data-background-image]")

Comment: @SarasotaSun please ask a new question.

Comment: @SarasotaSun Samuel is right about asking a separate question as this has nothing to do with the question. Anyway, from reference to `this.bar= el.querySelectorAll(".bar");`, you can use `this.bar = el.querySelectorAll('[data-src][data-background-image]')`, you can use the selector as it is in querySelector